# Running "laravel new" command in laravel project

Tags: php, laravel

I accidentally ran the `laravel new` command in a laravel project, which apparently deleted **autoload_real.php**

I get these error messages when running `php artisan serve`:

> "PHP Warning:  require(C:\xampp\htdocs\e-commerce\vendor\composer/../symfony/polyfill-ctype/bootstrap.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\e-commerce\vendor\composer\autoload_real.php on line 66
>
> Warning: require(C:\xampp\htdocs\e-commerce\vendor\composer/../symfony/polyfill-ctype/bootstrap.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\e-commerce\vendor\composer\autoload_real.php on line 66
>   PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required 'C:\xampp\htdocs\e-commerce\vendor\composer/../symfony/polyfill-ctype/bootstrap.php' (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\xampp\htdocs\e-commerce\vendor\composer\autoload_real.php on line 66
>
> Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required 'C:\xampp\htdocs\e-commerce\vendor\composer/../symfony/polyfill-ctype/bootstrap.php' (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\xampp\htdocs\e-commerce\vendor\composer\autoload_real.php on line 66"

Is there a way to get back **autoload_real.php**?

Comment: Depends upon what all happened in laravel new command? Is your composer.json intact? If yes, then just doing composer install should fix it? Delete composer.lock before doing this though. Let it generate a new fresh lock file.

Comment: Thats why you have to use git

Answer (score 1):

Just run:

```
composer update
```

inside your project, it should fix it.

Comment: I ran both composer update and composer install, launched a new server but my project doesn't appear, i get the Laravel homepage instead, what can I do about that?

Comment: What do you mean by "the Laravel homepage"? Why haven't you mentioned that in your question?

Answer (score 0):

Check if the file actually exists. If it's missing, but the folder 'symfony/polyfill-ctype' is there and  empty, try to delete vendor folder and run `composer install` again. It might be that `composer install` crashed previous time and it thinks the package is there. That was the case for me.